# Watch Kit notification from IOS App

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I develop an apple watch application. I want a simple behavior : when i press a button on iPhone on paired watch app i want to appear a notification. Is this possible?
I use watch OS 2 and my watch app communicates perfect with iPhone app and vice versa via WatchConectivity.
So using WCSession i can notify watch app but how can i display a controller in notification style, i mean as this

[image]

I saw that on controller that inherits from WKUserNotificationInterfaceController exist

```
- (void)didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification withCompletion:(void (^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType))completionHandler {
```

How can i make this method to be called? I tried on watch create a UILocalNotification

```
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.category = @"myCategory";
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:8];
notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hello! This is Local Notification!" forKey:@"Notification"];
notification.userInfo = infoDict;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

The problem is that in watch doesn't exist UIApplication so i could't schedule the notification. I made the same thing on iOS application but in this case i got the notification on iPhone.
I have to say that on watch app exists an NotificationInterfaceController with category name "myCategory".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a UILocalNotification **on your iPhone**

`UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.category = @"myCategory";
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:8];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Hello! This is Local Notification!" forKey:@"Notification"];
    notification.userInfo = infoDict;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];`

2. Lock your iPhone.
3. Notification appear on your Apple Watch and iPhone.
4. `didReceiveLocalNotification` on WatchApp is called.

POINT: You have to lock iPhone.